# iOS: What does tint color actually do?

Tags: ios, tintcolor

Suppose a segmented control's tint color is set to RGB(69, 175, 225) but the actually color from color picker range from (top most) RGB(146, 181, 211) to (bottom most) RGB(82, 118, 147).

So how can I expect the actually displayed color of the segmented control. For example, if I want the color of the bottom most point is RGB(69, 175, 225), what is the RGB value should I set?

Comment: @CRDave Link has moved to: http://betaful.com/post/82668813001/actual-colors-from-apple-ios-tintcolor

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The tint is a color on which some fancy visual effects (glossy reflections and so on) is applied. iOS applies them to app icons, tab bars, navigation bars and many other things. I think it would be wrong for you to make any assumptions as to what the local color for a given pixel is for a given tint, given these visual effects vary from UIElement to UIElement and *probably* from one OS version to another.