# Why call color "tint color" not directly color?

Tags: ios

In `iOS` many control's color property are called **tintColor**, why not directly use **color**. By the way, my native language is not `English`.

Comment: Go through this link and see the difference between the color and the tint color http://www.betaful.com/2011/10/actual-colors-from-apple-ios-tintcolor/ and here is a possible duplication of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307989/ios-what-does-tint-color-actually-do

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: What does tint color actually do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307989/ios-what-does-tint-color-actually-do)

Answer (score 2):

Because iOS controls tend to use gradients and other visual effects. So the color you give changes the tint of the various colours used, it doesn't give you the specific color you ask for.