# What is difference between textColor and tintColor in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton, textcolor, tintcolor

I know this is a silly question but I cannot figure out what is the exact difference between the `textColor` and `tintColor` properties of `UIButton`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307989/ios-what-does-tint-color-actually-do  Refer this....

Comment: Can't you just try it out and see by yourself ? Or read the doc ?
Tint always change the whole appearance (background, border, reflects etc.) while textColor change the text color.

Comment: question shows no effort

Answer (score 6):

**Tint color** tint to define a key color that indicates interactivity and selection state for UI elements throughout the app.

**Text Color** is color of text object represented in label, textfield etc...

Answer (score 2):

`tintColor` is the main color of the component, the `textColor` change the color of the text inside button. I recommend to use `setTitleColor:forState`.